# Only few elements of a model renders in forge viewer

Tags: javascript, react-redux, autodesk-forge, viewer, autodesk-viewer

I m using Forge Viewer for ReactNative app for iPad, using WEBVIEW I was able to get the model in viewer but it only renders few elements at first, then only after manually clicking "showAll" in context-menu, it displays all the element.

Is there a way to render all the model at once, I also tried using `viewer.showAll()` to render all but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading the same model on a non-iPad viewer? (e.g. computer browser) Same behavior?

As you made it work with `.showAll()`, I would suggest watching for geometry loaded event and run it, as shown below:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, function(e){
  viewer.showAll();
})
```